# Readin wordfiles The file appears to be corrupted

Tags: c#

How comes that there is a error thrown for files that are 'corrupted' but they do not exist in the folder that is searched for **~$test.docx** 
Can I somehow ignore these files ?

```
 string path ="D:/Users/Bole/TSM/";
      foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,"*.docx"))
        {
            {
                //Open the doc File
                var wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file);
```

Comment: They're temp files, and are prefixed with `~$`. [There is a microsoft support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/kb/211632) explaining them in relation to Word.

Comment: @Petesh how can I ignore that ?

Comment: I need to correct myself for the ~$ files; they're actually 'owner' files to indicate who's opened the file. However rory.ap's corrected answer should cover it.

Comment: These files are generated when you *open* a file in Word. It's your own code that creates them. To avoid them, pull all files into an array instead of enumerating, eg use `GetFiles` instead of `EnumerateFiles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as this, if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

if (!fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("~$"))
{
    var wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file);    
}
```

Additionally (as Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out), you are not doing yourself any favors by using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `foreach`.  The reason is that, every time it loops, the enumerator's `MoveNext` method calls `FindNextFile()` so new files can appear in the results.  Since a new `~$...docx` file is created every time this statement runs (see [this](https://superuser.com/a/405258/255404) for an explanation of why this happens):

```
var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file);
```

you're going to come across these files as the looping continues.  This can be avoided by using [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`, because the former just returns an array of file paths which doesn't change as you're looping through it; i.e. it's just a static list of files that is built at the *beginning* of the loop which ignores files that are created *while* the looping is happening.

Comment: Nice try would be so easy but nope somehow there is still a error thrown  The file appears to be corrupted.

Comment: Why would an error be thrown if it doesn't even try to open it?  That's the whole point of the `if` block.

Comment: Good answer, but AFAIK won't the `file` string be the full path? Wouldn't `.Contains("~$")` suit better?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in FormatChanger.exeAdditional information: The file appears to be corrupted.

Comment: @rory.ap - no problem. Good idea with using a `FileInfo` object :)

Comment: @TamoDaleko -- Are you *sure* it's doing what you think it's doing?  Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code while observing the state of the variables?  The `if` should prevent it from entering the body where it would even try to open the file.  My guess is it's doing something different than what you think, and the only way to know is to debug.

Comment: @rory.ap the `~$` files are generated when Word opens a file. They appear in the search results because the original code uses `EnumerateFiles`, so it returns the newly created temporary files. Switching to `GetFiles` will reduce the need for filtering dramatically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- Is it calling `EnumerateFiles` on every loop iteration though?  Or only once, at the start?

Comment: @rory.ap `EnumerateFiles` returns the first data as soon as the underlying OS method returns (I thinkg it's [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)). The enumerator's `MoveNext` method actually calls `FindNextFile` so new files *can* appear in the results. In this case, this can be a problem

Comment: @TamoDaleko -- make sure you take note of my update.